# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host when RMI server is child process of RMI client

Tags: java, rmi

I have two Java programs - RMIServer and RMIClient. Everything just works as expected, if I launch them as two separate Java invocations. That is

`$ java -cp someclasspath server.mainserverclass` &

`$ java -cp someclasspath client.mainclientclass`

But in my project, it so happens that I need the client java program to spawn the server and then connect to it. I used both the `runtime.exec()` method and ProcessBuilder to spawn a server instance, but when I do that I get the following:

```
.Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException:  
    Connection refused to host: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; nested exception is:
```

But the interesting part is that if manually kill the RMIClient instance, the RMIServer gets orphaned(parent is `pid:1`), and then if I run the RMIClient, I can connect to orphaned RMI server just fine!

So, in seems like when the RMIServer and RMIClient have a parent-child relationship, I am unable to connect via RMI.

Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

*****ANSWER***** (Apparently I do not have enough reputation to answer my own question :-)

This was my mistake. The RMIServer and RMIClient classes were instantiated in two separate Java  threads. The RMIClient class for instantiated *before* the RMIServer registered the remote object and hence I get this exception.

The parent child relationship is irrelevant to this problem. It so happened that order in which these classes were getting created was the root cause of the problem.

Comment: By any chance is your server outputting to stdout or stderr? If it is,  it's filling the buffer because you're not reading it from the `Process` object and it will cause it to block / lock. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: I did think about that. I am reading both stdout and stderr of the child process and redirecting it. I can confirm that looking that the messages it prints. So, I doubt if the buffers are filling up.

Answer (score 0):

> it so happens that I need the client java program to spawn the server
>   and then connect to it

Why? In that circumstance you don't even need RMI let alone the second JVM. Just create the remote object in the current JVM and call its methods directly.

RMI itself is completely unaware of the parent/child relationship so I wouldn't pursue that line of investigation. The exception string 'Connection refused to host: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1' is extremely suspicious. Where did you get the stub for the remote object? That's where the connect target comes from.

Comment: By design, the server and client are supposed to run on different machines, but I am writing a integration test framework, which requires client and server to be spawned from the same process.(just to make is easier for users to run integration test).

Comment: " The exception string 'Connection refused to host: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1' is extremely suspicious. Where did you get the stub for the remote object? That's where the connect target comes from

Comment: @user1013840 what exactly is the point of quoting my own words back at me?

Comment: Here is how I am looking up the remote stub:Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            archive = (Archive)registry.lookup(Archive.SERVICE_NAME);

Comment: "what exactly is the point of quoting my own words back at me? " - sorry about that, I tried to copy paste your comment and add my response, but before that I hit return and it saved it as a comment :-)

Comment: @user1013840 you can edit comments for 5 minutes you know. I think you need to show the code where you start the registry, start and monitor the child VM, create and bind the remote objects. On the face of it what you have posted is impossible ;-)