# RMI server behind NAT Connection refused to host

Tags: java, rmi

I have this RMI server that I am trying to connect to from home and I get this error message:

java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: XX.XXX.XX.XXX; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
public GUILogic(GUI gui) throws NotBoundException, MalformedURLException, RemoteException{
        super();
        this.gui = gui;  
        String objectname = "chatter";

        String url = "rmi://" + hostname + "/" + objectname;

        cf = (ChatFront) Naming.lookup(url);


    }
```

I have port forwarded the port 1099 (on the server computer), when I try http://www.canyouseeme.org/,  I find the port. Every firewall is down on my computer and the server.  The server is working fine if I set it up on a LAN.

What can the problem be?

Comment: did you look at below link?? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.rmi.ConnectException%3A+Connection+refused+to+hos

Comment: check this, might help you first... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898120/java-rmi-connectexception-connection-refused-to-host-when-rmi-server-is-child-p

Comment: possible duplicate of [RMI server behind NAT java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018812/rmi-server-behind-nat-java-rmi-connectexception-connection-refused-to-host)

Comment: EJP, it may be a duplicate of that one, but there are no answers to be found for either. :(  I don't blame him for asking again.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the exact same issue.

I fixed it by setting a hostname, which can be resolved by both server (behind NAT) and client.

Then, I added this arg to the server, in the java command line :

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=yourhostname
```

And it worked.

On the server side, a simple getRegistry worked perfectly.

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

Don't forget to nat registry and exported object ports.